# how to use call_user_func_array() function in laravel-5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

i am using a github repo (https://gist.github.com/mcaskill/baaee44487653e1afc0d#file-function-array-group-by-php) code and i am using that repo code in laravel and i am getting error

error :

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'array_group_by' not found or invalid function name

code :

```php
foreach ($grouped as $key => $value) {
    $params = array_merge([ $value ], array_slice($args, 2, func_num_args()));
    $grouped[$key] = call_user_func_array("array_group_by", $params);
}
```

I havn't use `call_user_func_array` before I don't know how to use this function in Laravel also I have tries `$this->array_group_by` but then I am getting error:

> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\abcController::array_group_by(), 1 passed in..

Comment: Is this function declared in the global namespace? if it is a method on your class then use `[$this, 'array_group_by']`. Even better yet, don't use `call_user_func_array`, but just call the function directly

Comment: Arer you sure that the function `array_group_by` is loaded? You can check with `function_exists('array_group_by');`

Comment: Thanks guys GertdePagter & KFoobar.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the array_group_by() function before calling it add the below function above your code or use this file in your code

```
function array_group_by(array $array, $key)
{
    if (!is_string($key) && !is_int($key) && !is_float($key) && !is_callable($key) ) {
        trigger_error('array_group_by(): The key should be a string, an integer, or a callback', E_USER_ERROR);
        return null;
    }
    $func = (!is_string($key) && is_callable($key) ? $key : null);
    $_key = $key;
    // Load the new array, splitting by the target key
    $grouped = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $key = null;
        if (is_callable($func)) {
            $key = call_user_func($func, $value);
        } elseif (is_object($value) && property_exists($value, $_key)) {
            $key = $value->{$_key};
        } elseif (isset($value[$_key])) {
            $key = $value[$_key];
        }
        if ($key === null) {
            continue;
        }
        $grouped[$key][] = $value;
    }
    // Recursively build a nested grouping if more parameters are supplied
    // Each grouped array value is grouped according to the next sequential key
    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        foreach ($grouped as $key => $value) {
            $params = array_merge([ $value ], array_slice($args, 2, func_num_args()));
            $grouped[$key] = call_user_func_array('array_group_by', $params);
        }
    }
    return $grouped;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer more. because this kind of answers are discourage by stack overflow community.